# Find the series defined on a custom set

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{n \in \Bbb N: n=1$ or the only prime factors of n are 2 and 3, like $6\in A, 10\notin A$.
Let $S=\sum_{n\in A} {1\over n},$

Then:

1. $A$ is finite
2. $S$ is a divergent series
3. $S=3$
4. $S=6$

How to proceed with this? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a classical trick for this, whenever you have at most a finite number of prime factors in the terms of your sum. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of these prime factors (in this case 2,3). Then:

$$\sum_{n\in A}\frac{1}{n}=\prod_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1}<\infty.$$

To prove this, for each term in the product, expand it: $(1-1/p)^{-1}=1+1/p+1/p^2+...$. Now notice that multiplying these for all such $p\in\mathcal{P}$ gives you all numbers of the form $1/p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$, and by uniqueness of factorization, only once for each term. Note that the sum will *diverge* if $\mathcal{P}$ includes all primes (i.e. becomes the harmonic sum).

Answer (score 3):

$2, 2^2,\cdots, 2^n$ are all in $A$

$A$ it not finite.

$A = \{2^i3^j: i,j \in \mathbb N\}$

$S =\sum_\limits{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_\limits{i=0}^{\infty} \frac 1{2^i3^j} =\left(\sum_\limits{j=0}^{\infty}\frac1{3^j}\right)\left(\sum_\limits{i=0}^{\infty} \frac 1{2^i}\right)$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i 3 ^j} =\frac{1}{1-1/2} \frac{1}{1-1/3} =\underbrace{\color{red}{3}}_{ \text{3.}} 
\end{eqnarray*}